# Simple MediaWiki question

Tags: mediawiki, localhost, mongodb

I'm thinking about making a mediawiki website. At first I'd like to try it at `localhost`. I'm running Kubuntu 11.10, so I did:

```
sudo aptitude install apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql php5-cli
```

And I also fetched the latest mediawiki to:

```
/home/boris/Its/sites/mediawiki-1.17.0
```

Now I'm supposed to open

```
http://localhost/home/boris/Its/sites/mediawiki-1.17.0/index.php
```

But firefox says the page is not found. While `http://localhost` works. If I get it right - I have to open `index.php` to install mediawiki. So my question is - what do I do wrong?

I'm really sorry for this is might be a very simple question.

By the way do I have to make a db beforehand? Is it possible to use mongoDB as a db with mediawiki?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* by default apache will look into `/srv/www` for websites, not the users home directory.  The first thing I would check is where apache is looking.

If you search the internet for terms like "apache .conf virtual host" you should find several how-to guides. [Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) is the official documentation on virtual hosts.

You don't need to create a database, as this can be done during the installation. However you do need to tell it details about the database installation. It needs to be MySQL or PostgreSQL - see the [installation guide](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Installation). When you get index.php working [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aConfig_script) takes you through the options.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I'm stupid, I found the [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MediaWiki) which explains how this should be done. I wonder why mediawiki docs have skipped these details.

Comment: I think that the MediaWiki people probably skipped the Apache details because that's a bit of a slippery slope; if you explain how to set up a web site in Apache, they might get roped into explaining how to install Apache on Debian, or some of the other distros, and it could get out of hand very quickly. They might want to add it as a prerequisite to the documentation, though...